# Pod install on existing project caused error with nanopb (Xcode13 + toolchain to swift 5.4)

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, xcode13

**Background:**

- After cloning an existing project, removed xcworkspace and podfile.lock, then ran pod install. There are about 20 pods in this project.
- Xcode version is 13.1 but I'm using toolchain because some pods have outdated syntax and Xcode won't build with Swift 5.5.

Now all other errors disappear but there are errors in nanopb instead.
For example:

- Semantic issue: function doesn't return NSString. (NSBundle.h)
- Parse issue: cannot find module Foundation. (in multiple .h files)

[(Screenshot) some of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g9Jz.png)

**Podfile**

```html
platform :ios, '13.0'

use_frameworks!

def projectname_pods
  # Pods for projectname
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
  pod 'Action'
  pod 'RxAlamofire'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView/Extended'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'ActiveLabel'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'DKImagePickerController'
  pod 'SimpleImageViewer'
  pod 'YouTubePlayer'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'SwiftPhotoGallery'
  pod 'SCLAlertView'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit/Swift'
  pod "RxGesture"
  pod 'ReadMoreTextView'
  pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
  pod 'MessageKit'
end

target 'projectname' do
    projectname_pods
end

target 'projectname-Dev' do
    projectname_pods
    
    target 'projectname' do
       inherit! :search_paths
       # Pods for testing
     end
end
```

**What I tried:**

- cleared derived data
- delete podfile.lock, xcworkspace, pods and install again

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you in advance!